# execute a cmd command with java to create a data basse

Tags: java, cmd, sqlite

my CMD command is to create a data basse withe Sqlite3
it's work with CMD but with java it's not 
My Code java :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd C:\Users...");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Sqlite3");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Sqlite3 DB.db");
```

Comment: are you trying to run cmd from java.. or is it just about accessing sql in java?

Comment: Doing a `cd` in a subprocess is useless, because its effect is local to the subprocess and you are still at the original working directory when it ends.

Comment: yes i'm trying to run cmd from java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You do not need to run standalone sqlite application with Runtime.exec. Better use a library the following way.

When you connect to a non-existent SQLite database, SQLite automatically creates a new database. Therefore, to create a new database, you just need to specify the database name and connect to it.

The following program creates a new SQLite database named test.db in the folder c:\sqlite\db.

```
package net.sqlitetutorial;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 *
 * @author sqlitetutorial.net
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * Connect to a sample database
     *
     * @param fileName the database file name
     */
    public static void createNewDatabase(String fileName) {

        String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db/" + fileName;

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
            if (conn != null) {
                DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
                System.out.println("The driver name is " + meta.getDriverName());
                System.out.println("A new database has been created.");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        // You will probably need to uncomment the following "class.forName"
        // and copy dependency configuration to your pom.xml
        // if you stumble upon "No suitable driver found" error.
        /*
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        */
        //Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        createNewDatabase("test.db");
    }

}
```

Source: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/create-database/

Comment: but when i do that, and instal the app in partition C:\ it 's dosen't work !! so try to do it like this with cmd command

Comment: What is the exact reason it doesn't work? Any exception thrown by java application? Incorrect path, no access to create or write to file maybe?

Comment: it's say i don't have access permission, but when i instal in partion D:\ it's work

Comment: One last question. After you create this sqlite3 file (no matter, my way or by running external cmd), do you need to operate on it somehow? Do you need to create tables, read and write data from your java code to this database?

Comment: yes of yes of course i need to create the data basse and the tables this in the fisrt time i run my app and after that i do the reading, writing and updates

Comment: Well it obviously means you have no reason to create a database using external tools. You have a library specifically designed to do it. The only thing left is to figure out why your java program doesn't have enough permissions to access file and eventually you will have to figure it out anyway, if you plan to access the database from your program. So I would strongly recommend not to invent the wheel and create database with `java.sql`.